# Why do I get JavaScript runtime error: Expected ')' when I'm adding a client-side event to a dynamically generated button?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am dynamically generating a aspxbutton and attaching a client-side event to it.

When the following code is executed,

```
Dim path As String = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath + "/PDF.aspx"
button.ClientSideEvents.Click = "window.open('" + path + "', '_blank');"
```

I get the following javascript error

```
JavaScript runtime error: Expected ')'
```

And i'm unsure why.  Appreciate the help!

Comment: Using the developer console of your browser, look at the HTML generated for the button. This will most likely reveal the source of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's expecting a `)` and isn't getting it. It's probably because the single and double quotes are getting messed up here:

```
button.ClientSideEvents.Click = "window.open('" + path + "', '_blank');"
```

Try escaping the single quotes using `\` like so:

```
button.ClientSideEvents.Click = "window.open(\'" + path + "\', \'_blank\');"
```